# How to compile Foundation source files?

Tags: sass, gulp, zurb-foundation

I would like to compile a "lite" version of Foundation framework.

I downloaded "scss" and "js" folders from foundation-sites GitHub repository (https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites) and I created the following Gulp tasks:

```
gulp.task('foundationCss', function(cb) {
  return gulp.src('foundation/scss/foundation.scss')
             .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
             .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
             .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + '/styles'));
});

gulp.task('foundationJs', function() {
  return gulp.src(['foundation/js/foundation.core.js',
                   'foundation/js/foundation.util.*.js',
                   'foundation/js/*.js'])
             .pipe(concat('foundation.min.js'))
             .pipe(minifyJs())
             .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + '/scripts'));
});
```

Is this the right way to do the job? I think something is wrong because I'm getting some layout problems. For example I get different outputs for the "topbar" html, that I use on latest Foundation 6 (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kXOmPA) and "my" Foundation 6 (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jAgQvL).

What's wrong with my Gulp tasks?

Answer (score 1):

For CSS you need to include Autoprefixer. For JavaScript you need to include Babel if you want your website to work in Safari, InternetExplorer and Edge (Browsers with no or limited Support for ES2015).

Take a look at: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html for JavaScript Setup and http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sass.html for CSS Setup.